# Как скачать файл с хостинга?

Tags: c++

Я пробовал подключить curl, но не выходит (делал по этим видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjNyT5PhNvI&t=1s , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_mXVZ6VJs4&t=1118s). Копаю яндекс и гугл уже 4 дня, пробую все, но не работает.
Выдает ошибку 
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__curl_easy_init в функции _main Test D:\C++Test\Test\Test\Test.obj 1
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__curl_easy_setopt в функции _main Test D:\C++Test\Test\Test\Test.obj 1
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__curl_easy_perform в функции _main Test D:\C++Test\Test\Test\Test.obj 1
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__curl_easy_cleanup в функции _main Test D:\C++Test\Test\Test\Test.obj 1

Есть ли другой способ скачивать файлы с хостинга? 
В дальнейшем я планирую использовать этот код в игре на UE4(для android и windows), поэтому я так понял что решение должно быть кроссплатформенное, а не только для windows.
Буду благодарен за примеры или ссылки на них.

Comment: Если это вопрос про UE, то там есть IHttpRequest из коробки и curl не нужен. https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/HTTP/index.html

Comment: Спасибо, пойду смотреть.

Comment: С курлом лучше разберитесь и прилинкуйте его номрально